# Finding the uniquely determined region of a PDE

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

(a) Solve the equation
$yu_x+xu_y=0$
 with the condition $u(0,y) =
e^{-y^2}$.
(b) In which region of the xy plane is the solution uniquely determined?

I did the first part but I don't understand how to do part b.  I read [this.](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=296358)

But I don't understand how the argument is based. A more clear explanation is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Exercise 1.2.7 in *Partial Differential Equations* by Strauss.

(a) The slope of characteristics is $x/y$. Solve 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y} \tag{1}
$$
by separating variables: $y\,dy=x\,dx$, hence $y^2/2=x^2/2+C$. Isolate $C$ here: 
$$y^2-x^2=C \tag{2}$$

The  general solution is $u(x,y)=f(y^2-x^2)$, an arbitrary function of the left side of (2). Plugging in the given condition $u(0,y) =
e^{-y^2}$, we get $$f(y^2)=e^{-y^2}\tag{3}$$ I prefer to use a new letter, such as $z$, for the argument of $f$. The function $f(z)=e^{-z}$ satisfies (3) and gives 
$$
{u(x,y)= e^{x^2-y^2}} \tag{4}
$$

(b) Looking at (3) more carefully, we see that it only involves the values of $f$ on $[0, \infty)$. Therefore, it is  satisfied by any function $f$ such that $f(z)=e^{-z}$ for $z\ge 0$. The values of $f$ for negative $z$ can be arbitrary. It follows that  the solution $u(x,y)=f(y^2-x^2)$ is uniquely determined in the region $y^2-x^2\ge 0$ (unpainted on the sketch below) but can be any function of the form $f(y^2-x^2)$ in the region $y^2-x^2  < 0$ (painted).

[image: regions]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I understand your answer with combination of the answer given just before the last answer at http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=296358. But can you say what is the importance of y=x and y=-x lines?In that answer it has been used.And how to think as why I should consider those two lines

Comment: @clarkson I incorrectly described the region $x^2-y^2\ge 0$ as "first and third quadrants". In fact these are sectors formed by the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$. The relevance of these two lines becomes clear if you rewrite the boundary equation $x^2-y^2=0$ as $(x-y)(x+y)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help given

Comment: The answer above has mixed up the region where the solution is uniquely determined. It is uniquely determined on $x^2\leq y^2$ (unpainted region).

Answer (score 0):

Another detailed explanation can be found in Exercise 4 [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~vedranso/Math425_Homework1_Solutions.pdf) and a simple one in 7b) [here](https://www.math.colostate.edu/~blumstei/MathDocs/Homework/M545PDEs/HW1.pdf).